# How to include Python.h in a 32-bit C program on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: c

Machine Type: x86-64-pc-linux-gnu.

I've been trying to include "python3.11/Python.h" in my C program. It works when I use "-m64" option and fails when I use "-m32", giving out "fatal error: i386-linux-gnu/python3.11/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory".

When I looked into /usr/include, I found that there is no such "i386-linux-gnu" folder under this path.

I have already installed "gcc-multilib", C programs not using Python.h can be successfully compiled in 32 bits. Now what should I do to use Python.h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the compiler is unable to find the **Python 3.11** header files for a **32-bit** architecture. This could be due to the fact that the **32-bit Python** development headers are not installed on your system.

So, how?

1. Install the 32-bit Python development header

```
sudo apt-get install python3.11-dev:i386
```

2. Locate the Python.h file

```
locate Python.h
```

3. Compile your C program with the correct include path

```
gcc -m32 -I/path/to/Python.h your_program.c
```

*Replace **/path/to/Python.h** with the actual path to the Python.h file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's it! I didn't know how to install a i386 lib. Problem solved by `sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev:i386`. Thank you for your answer.